# More than one value at a time?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a method to include more than one value at a time. Firstly, here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit_link').click(function() {
        $('.text_wrapper').hide();
        var data=$('.text_wrapper').html();
        $('.edit').show();
        $('.editbox').html(data);
        $('.editbox').focus();
    });

    $(".editbox").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });

    $(".editbox").change(function() {
        $('.edit').hide();
        var boxval = $(".editbox").val();
        var dataString = 'data=' + boxval;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_profile_ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.text_wrapper').html(boxval);
                $('.text_wrapper').show();
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $('.edit').hide();
        $('.text_wrapper').show();
    });
});
```

I want to have more than one field. I want to edit more than one entry at a time, instead of simply re-writing the code for each different value. Is there a way I can include them in the code? I tried this but had no luck:

```
$('.edit_link','.edit_link2','.edit_link3').click(function() {
    $('.text_wrapper','.text_wrapper2','.text_wrapper3').hide();
    var data=$('.text_wrapper','.text_wrapper2','.text_wrapper3').html();
```

Hopefully you get what I mean by this, I want to include more values but cannot achieve this, does anyone have some advice or a simply way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all in one string, for example:

```
$('.text_wrapper, .text_wrapper2, .text_wrapper3').hide();
```

But you can't read out the values with `html()` on multiple elements at the same time.

So for example use:

```
data = $('.text_wrapper').html();
data += $('.text_wrapper2').html();
data += $('.text_wrapper3').html();
```

But this depends on how you wanna have your data in the end.